# Covariance of Random Proportions in Multinomial Counts

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis

In Agresti's Categorical Data Analysis Second Edition, at Section 14.1.4, there is a proof of the Asymptotic Normality of Functions of Multinomial Counts. It is stated that for a vector of responses $Y_i = ( Y_ {i1},...Y_{iN})$ where $Y_{ij} = 1 $ when a response falls in the jth cell and $Y_{ij} = 0 $ otherwise, then $E(Y_{ij}) = \pi_j$ and $cov(Y_i)= \Sigma$ $\thinspace$  $i= 1,...,n.$

The covariance matrix for entries where $j \neq k$ has a form in vector notation:
$\Sigma = diag(\pi) - \pi\pi{\prime}$.
If *P* is a sample mean of n independent observations i.e. $P = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_{ij} /n$ then it is stated that $cov(p) =  [diag(\pi) - \pi\pi{\prime}]/n$. My attempt to replicate the analysis is as follows:

$cov(p)$:

$\sigma_{jj} = \pi_j (1- \pi_j)/ n $ .

$\sigma_{jk} = cov({\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{ij}/n}, {\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{ik}/n})$ $\thinspace$ $j \neq k$

The last expression breaks down as follows:
$1/n^2 \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n cov(Y_{ij}, Y_{ik})= 
1/n^2 \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n (-\pi_{j} \pi_{k})= 
(n^2/n^2)(-\pi_{j} \pi_{k})$.
In the text, this should have been $(-\pi_{ij} \pi_{ik})/n$. Would be glad to know what I am missing.

*Editted:*

Incorporating the suggestion to change the index from *i* to *l*, this is what I have:

$\sigma_{jk} = cov({\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{ij}/n}, {\sum_{l=1}^n Y_{lk}/n})$ $\thinspace$ $j \neq k$

$1/n^2 \sum_{i=1}^n cov(Y_{ij}, Y_{1k}) + cov(Y_{ij}, Y_{2k})...+ cov(Y_{ij}, Y_{nk})$

$1/n^2 [cov(Y_{1j}, Y_{1k}) + cov(Y_{1j}, Y_{2k})...+ cov(Y_{1j}, Y_{nk})] + 
[cov(Y_{2j}, Y_{1k}) + cov(Y_{2j}, Y_{2k})...+ cov(Y_{2j}, Y_{nk})] +...+
[cov(Y_{nj}, Y_{1k}) + cov(Y_{nj}, Y_{2k})...+ cov(Y_{nj}, Y_{nk})]
$.

So equating covariances where $i \neq l$ to zero, I will have:
$1/n^2 [(-\pi_{j} \pi_{k}) + 0...+ 0)] + 
[0 + (-\pi_{j} \pi_{k}))...+ 0)] +...+
[0 + 0...+ (-\pi_{j} \pi_{k}))] = (1/n^2) n (-\pi_{j} \pi_{k})= (1/n) (-\pi_{j} \pi_{k})
$

Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write nested summations as $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n f(i)$  since it is then unclear which summation index the $i$ in the expression $f(i)$ refers to. To avoid this confusion, try starting from
\begin{equation}
\sigma_{jk} = \operatorname{Cov}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{ij}, \sum_{l=1}^n Y_{lk}\right),j\neq k
\end{equation}
(there is nothing wrong with using $i$ in two different sum as in the corresponding expression in the question, except this formulation may make it easier to not get confused in the next step). There is also a typo(?) in the question in that you should have $j\neq k$ rather than $i \neq j$.

Comment: Thanks Juho. I have editted my question  incorporating your suggestion. Let me know if I am on the right path.